# How to find points which have points snapped on them

Tags: postgis

I have a table in which I have a geometry of multipoints (col1), another geometry of multipoints(col2) and another col3 with same type
Now I need check for all the points in col1, if it has a point in col2 in distance 50 m, then take that point. Else, take col3 for that case.
Please tell a way to do that.

Comment: What have you tried? The queries for finding a point in X distance are pretty popular on the internet.

Comment: Ya. I can use st_dwithin for that. Problem is I have to do step by step taking one point at a time.

Comment: Then show what you have thus far. Right now your question looks like you didn't even try doing anything yourself.

Comment: I found a solution. I can take buffer of the col2 and check if it intersects with any of points in col1.

Answer (score 0):

Take buffer of the col2 and check if it intersects with any of points in col1.
And write a switch case handling the same.